# File Name not exactly shown

Tags: jobname, currfile

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{currfile}

\begin{document}

%File Name: ÖüğşiÇ.tex

\jobname

\currfilename

\end{document}
```

And output:

[image]

Is it possible below the image?

[image]

Comment: Using in a filename others characters that numbers or basic Latin alphabet is still today ask for problems. However, at least with `xelatex`, without the first 3 lines of your preamble  and using `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}`  the ouput is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

indicates you are using pdfTeX, an 8-bit engine. This cannot represent the full range of Unicode code points internally, and there is only a 1-to-1 mapping between 8-bit and Unicode code points for slots 0-127: essentially for A-Za-z in terms of letters. To get other characters to print, the `inputenc` package makes various code points *active*, and uses this to remap what look to the engine like 2, 3 or 4 'characters' to a single slot in the font.

This works fine for normal text (if you simply type in `ÖüğşiÇ` it will print) but not for `\jobname` as it is a 'string': the category codes of the characters are already set before it's read. You have a couple of options:

- Use a Unicode engine (XeTeX, LuaTeX) which does handle the full range, plus a font that has the right slots set up (basically `\usepackage{fontspec}`)
- Tell TeX to rescan (reassign category codes) the input: a bit tricky due to the way `\jobname` works. Something like

  ```
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\scantokens{\jobname}}\x
  ```

Comment: perfect working...